# Can someone explain to me why my edit got rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I don't see anything that will make [my edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/196303) (revision 3) be rejected.

I made some minor changes, and improved its grammar, as well as its formatting (As what I also put on the "edit summary").  As you can see, two reviewers approved my edit, while the OP of the answer rejected it.

Upon looking at the [revisions](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/194593/revisions), the OP rolled it back to revision 2, which is his edit.

Also, I don't see any reason to use triple backticks (three on both sides) for an inline code, instead of just using one (one on both sides).  It will both work either you use three or one, with an exception of a backtick inside a code.  (Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code-spans) for more help about markdown)

I am also just following the English grammar rules, such as capitalizing the first letter of the first word of the sentence, as well as capitalizing proper nouns.

I'm just trying to improve a post by editing it, but all I get is a "-2" on my reputation on Android.SE

Comment: It may be because they're unfamiliar with the UI, and unintentionally overrode the approval

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything in that edit which should have caused it to be rejected.

However, I think that your Meta question here should have been asked at the Meta of the site where you made the edit (i.e. [Meta Android Enthusiasts](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com)) instead.

Comment: Yeah.  Same here.  I also don't see anything which causes it to be rejected.  Maybe the OP doesn't want to edit his answer.